# NSNotifier on Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm building a mac daemon, from scratch.

Here's a simplified version of the code.

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "notifier.h"

    int new_notification();

    notifier *not;

    int main () {
            @autoreleasepool {
                    not = [[[notifier alloc] init] autorelease];
                    pid_t pid;
                    pid = fork();
                    if(pid > 0) {
                            printf("my child id is %d\n", pid);
                            exit(0);
                    }
                    while(1) {
                            int n = new_notification();
                            if(n > 0) {
                                    NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
                                    notification.title = @"Hello, World!";
                                    notification.informativeText = @"A notification";
                                    notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                                    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];

                                    printf("new notification : count = %d !!\n", n);
                            }
                            sleep(1);
                    }
            }
            return 0;
    }



    int new_notification() {
            return [not get_notifications];
    }
```

I don't see the notification on my window though, I think I have to make my application a "key" application, if so, how do it do that? I can see the output on my terminal though, and on checking if

```
    (NSClassFromString(@"NSUserNotificationCenter")==nil)
            I get FALSE
```

Comment: does that notification code work from a standard app?

Comment: also what is the result of `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]`?

Comment: I haven't tried it on the standard app... But I found this piece of code on StackOverflow, where it said, it does. The expected result of this code is a notification on the top right corner of the screen with the title as "Hello, World!" and message as "A notification" along with a sound.

Comment: so you are assuming then... seems like you are expecting the SO community to do that for you. You also didnt answer if `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]` returns nil or not.

Comment: another thing that needs to be pointed out is that `fork()`ing a process isnt how you write a daemon on Mac OS X. you should use `launchd` which explicitly forbids calling `fork()`

Answer (score 1):

Extended comments that I hope answer your issue...

If your app is active, the notification is unlikely to be displayed.  But you'd be able to find it in the notification center.  (Notifications draw a user's attention to an app that they're not already looking at.)

I'd suggest trying `[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory]` to make it clear your app isn't in the foreground but I'm not totally certain whether `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` aka `NSApp` is something you'd use with a daemon.

Part of your issue may actually be that without invoking `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` and telling it to `run` you never become an app, so you can't use the notification center... or become an accessory. But I'm not certain of that either.